# Joomla File not found error

Tags: joomla

I have clone the website from http://www.betaekwondo.com.au/ to http://www.be-ma.com.au/index.php 
     everything works fine but I am stuck and getting 404 file not found error only on below link 
     http://www.be-ma.com.au/programs.html
     http://www.be-ma.com.au/be-fit.html
     http://www.be-ma.com.au/programs/taekwondo.html
all links working in main site i just copy the files and database and change in configuration file as required. Please share you knowledge*

Answer (score 0):

Links are not error And no problem!